# Run php script inside JavaScript at regular intervals using ajax or any method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a index.php with a javascript function Loaddata()

```
function loaddata(){

<?php 
$data = //connects to database and gives new data        
?> 

var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;   
}

setInterval(loaddata,3000);
```

I understand the fact that php scripts can only be run once when the page is loaded and it cannot be run again using set interval method. Can someone please guide me how to run the php script at regular intervals inside my index.php using ajax or some other method. My javascript variable "data" depends upon the php script to gets its value.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wondering how to do it.
Echo the PHP value that you want ajax to get for you.
Do an ajax request to the php page to get the data.

```
$.ajax({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'time.php',
      data: {
        
        'ajax': true
      },
      success: function(data) {
          
      console.log(data)
      
       
      }
    });

// Second Method

    $.get('time.php',function(data){
        
        console.log(data);
        
    });
```

PHP file

```
if ($_GET['ajax']) {

echo "HELOOO";
}

//if using the 2nd method just echo

echo "hi second method";
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, using ajax to get data from a PHP page on the front page is a good way. The way you write this code is fine, too. I suggest writing like this,

```html
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data);?>;
function loaddata(){
  // use data
}
setInterval(loaddata,3000);
```

I think it is more clear

Comment: Hey Sorry !! This is not what im looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ajax call to retrive data from php and call that function in setInterval function something like this.

```
function demofunc()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            // do your thing
        }
    });
}
setInterval(demofunc,3000);
```